# Can forcing an opponent away give an attack of opportunity to an ally?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack

Assume my ally was fighting an enemy at close range.  If I cast a spell, ability, whatever that forced the enemy away, would that trigger an attack of opportunity for my ally?

Answer (score 2):

### If certain conditions are met

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach. To make the opportunity attack, you use your reaction to make one melee attack against the provoking creature. The attack occurs right before the creature leaves your reach.

The creature must *move* - that is, the "spell, ability, whatever" must cause the creature to use its own movement - moving the creature without doing that does not meet the preconditions for that. So, for example, [Dissonant Whispers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dissonant-whispers) does, [Thorn Whip](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thorn-whip) does not.

It must move the creature out of the reach of the ally. if it moves them within that reach, that doesn't trigger the preconditions either.

Your ally must be able to see the creature that moved - an invisible enemy or a blind ally doesn't work.

Finally, your ally must have a Reaction available and the ability to make a melee attack.